# Plotting an array in python does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am new to python and I want to plot some array but I have problems with reproducing this [EXAMPLE](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html). As soon as I run this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

a bunch of errors come instead of a plot.

The errors say:
[image]

Could somebody let me know what is wrong?

Comment: it seems that you lack the tkinter library. How did you install pylab? Using pip it should have installed it automatically. If you installed pylab manually you may have not installed all the dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your python installation / matplotlib installation is incomplete. Your version of matplotlib uses tkinter, which is missing. Try uninstalling matplotlib, tkinter, and then reinstalling them both

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

If this does not work either, as tkinter is a library that's bundled along with python by default and not on Python Packaging Index (pip), you will have to uninstall python, and then reinstall it

Comment: Ok it does not work. Is there some dummy manual how to install python 3.5 correctly? I am in windows 10 environment, if that matters.

Comment: Perhaps you could try uninstalling with a software like `Iobit Uninstaller` (one of the software that clean uninstalls in Windows, that I can remember) and then reinstalling, Note that when installing, Tick `Add python to  Path` or some option that should sound like that

Answer (score 0):

works for me in python 3.5.

The error message says you're missing tkinter try

```
pip install tkinter
```

Comment: tkinter is not there in pypi